# Where is Metamask's "request sign" used?

Tags: web3js, signature

[image]

Sometimes when using web3 Dapp, when connecting metamask, a signature request appears like a picture.

Can you tell me an example of using signed data in this case?

*In web3.js, there is a function that sends a request through "web3.eth.personal.sign", is it the same content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of using signed data using Metamask is authenticating websites, such as when you tried to sign into OpenSea.

No, signing data with Metamask in this case uses `eth-sig-util`, not `web3.eth.personal.sign`.

See:

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#a-brief-history

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-personal.html